# Android Widget : big image scrollable - out of memory

Tags: android, widget, out-of-memory, android-remoteview

I try to create a **widget** on Android, showing a **dynamically generated image**, bigger than the widget.

### 1. How I did

This can be done with a **ListView**, and the adapter is a **RemoteViewsService** where I build my bitmap. Then I create a **RemoteViews**, and I call setImageViewBitmap with my bitmap.
It's working, the widget displays well my image width a vertical scroll (what I want !).

> Widget => ListView => setRemoteAdapter(RemoteViewsService) => getViewAt() => RemoteViews => create a view and retrieve bitmap => setImageViewBitmap

### 2. My memory problem

When the widget is resized, I redraw the bitmap and do the job again (Image depends on widget size). And I see memory growing each time up to **out of memory**...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can delete an object in java by assigning null to it.

Comment: And call gc using Runtime.getRuntime().gc()

Comment: I can't assign null because the remoteView is returned in the implementation of RemoteViewsFactory.getViewAt()   :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it could be useful for someone.

Before :

> Create view and retrieve the bitmap

Solution :

> Create directly the Bitmap. setImageViewBitmap works without loosing memory :-)